Accessing a named range to insert a value does not work
I have a piece of code that is trying to overwrite the value in a named range, but I am getting <Object doesn't support this property or method>
Sub CheckStuff()

    If Evaluate("Table1RowCount") > Evaluate("Table1LastRowFixed") Then
 
        ActiveWorkbook.Range("Table1LastRowFixed").Value = Evaluate("Table1RowCount")
  
    End If

End Sub

The error occurs at the "ActiveWorkbook.Range" line. Table1RowCount & Table1LastRowFixed are both named ranges with workbook level scope hosting constant values. I am trying to update one of them based on a condition. As you can see the Evaulate function works on both name ranges, but when I try to use the Range to update on of them I am getting the error.
Please note that I have tried "Thisworkbook.Range" and "Range" by itself without much success.
Any help is appreciated.

ActiveWorkbook.Range: A Range is a property of a Worksheet, not a Workbook.

"named ranges with workbook level scope hosting constant values" is a bit ambiguous.
Do the names refer to worksheet cells, or to constants? If constants then:
ActiveWorkbook.Names("Table1LastRowFixed").RefersTo=Evaluate("Table1RowCount")

Thanks Tim. Your suggestion worked and yes the named range was referring to constants and NOT TO cells on the sheet.

Ranges and names are not quite the same thing, however you can sort of make them that way using RefersToRange.
Try this:
If Evaluate("Table1RowCount") > Evaluate("Table1LastRowFixed") Then
    
    ThisWorkbook.Names("Table1LastRowFixed").RefersToRange.Value = Evaluate("Table1RowCount")

End If

I'd also recommend minimizing all the hard coding... too many quotes and possible typing errors. Consider this...
    Const nnTableRowCount = "Table1RowCount"
    Const nnLastRowFixed = "Table1LastRowFixed"
    
    If Evaluate(nnTableRowCount) > Evaluate(nnLastRowFixed) Then
        
        ThisWorkbook.Names(nnLastRowFixed).RefersToRange.Value = Evaluate(nnTableRowCount)
    
    End If



Hello pgSystemTester, Thanks for your response, but your solution did not work, but the one provided by Tim Williams. I will certainly follow your suggestion about the hard coding part.
